# .NET Custom Language Registration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8.1

For some requirements, I had to register some custom languages with .NET like en-PK(English Pakistan), en-LB(English Lebanon) and some more. Since these cultures are not predefined with .NET.

So I have registered these custom cultures with .NET. The same is imported as a language to Sitecore CMS and items are versioned with the new custom language i.e., items versioned to en-PK(English Pakistan), en-LB(English Lebanon) and so on. The site is working without any issues.

This was created as an EXE and the same was run in the CE servers and i was able to create, add, Import and Export sitecore items to/from the newly created custom languages without any issues. The same exe had been run in all the CD servers.

Below is the code which was used to create custom language registration with .NET.

[image]

After that the site is configured with cloudflare. Now when I access site, I am getting the below attached issue,

[image]

Note:- I have never had this issue on my local or CE servers.

Any suggestions are welcome to resolve this one.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by "site is moved to cloudflare". From what I know, they don't provide any hosting services. If you could give some more details on what exact hosting provider you are using, then it would be easier to figure out how to run custom cultures registration there.

Comment: I meant the site is accessible via Cloudflare.

Comment: The issue was to due to one of the custom language was not moved to CD with its corresponding registry entry. Now the same is moved and the site is up and running.